# Batch Place Multiple Linked Files in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, batch-processing, actions

So I've got an insane amount of images to process through Photoshop, and I've worked it out that linking them is my best bet. Has anyone come across a script or action that would allow someone to import / place multiple linked files in one fell swoop? I've already discovered the alt+drag into Photoshop trick, but I still have to press enter to place each file.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This method takes a few steps – but it does accomplish what you want (I think)

- In Photoshop go to File > Scripts > Load Files into Stack *or...*
- In Bridge go to Tools > Photoshop > Load Files into Photoshop Layers
- Select all layers in the Layers Panel and run [this script](https://doc-0k-ao-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/ha0ro937gcuc7l7deffksulhg5h7mbp1/f3bn7iu92nmdg3cu6t89nca445l0t9iq/1500012000000/17185336498840124073/*/0Bwt5v3UObTCGT2c3ZklKMXYxWjA?e=download) to convert each layer to a Smart Object
- Select all layers in the Layers Panel, right-click on them and choose 'Convert to Linked'
- Select a folder to put the resulting PSBs into

Done

Comment: The link to your script no longer is working. Do you mind adding the text of your script to your answer?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your computer can handle having as many pictures open in Photshop as you need, what's wrong with drag and drop, and then just spam Enter as fast as you can till it's done?